# subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, dpkg

Here is the [virtualbox-4.3.prerm](https://gist.github.com/saiwaimaung/9413561) script.

[apt-cache policy virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox virtualbox-4.3](https://gist.github.com/saiwaimaung/9414098).

I was trying to install virtualbox-guess-additions-iso, and got the following error:

```
sudo aptitude install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgsoap1{a} virtualbox{a} virtualbox-dkms{a} virtualbox-guest-additions-iso  
virtualbox-qt{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/64.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 121 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-4.3 : Conflicts: virtualbox but 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.5 is to be  
installed.
              Conflicts: virtualbox-guest-additions-iso but 4.1.12-1 is to be 
installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
   Remove the following packages:
1)     virtualbox-4.3     


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libgsoap1{a} virtualbox{a} virtualbox-dkms{a} virtualbox-guest-additions-iso   
   virtualbox-qt{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   virtualbox-4.3{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/64.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 33.0 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 484051 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-4.3 ...
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-4.3 (--remove):
  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered   
while processing:
  virtualbox-4.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Comment: Post the pre-removal script. You can find it at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/pkgname.prerm`. Substitute the name of the package (probably `virtualbox`) for `pkgname`.

Comment: There's still missing information, please add the complete output.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dpkg --remove virtualbox-4.3`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha virtualbox-4.3.prerm: https://gist.github.com/saiwaimaung/9413561

Comment: @user2644318 paste it into the question, please.

Comment: @Braiam dpkg: error processing virtualbox-4.3 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1

Comment: Post `apt-cache policy virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox virtualbox-4.3` please.

Comment: @user2644318 again, post all info into the question, not the comments.

Comment: Could you edit your question instead.

Comment: cross posted http://askubuntu.com/questions/430908/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Perhaps try running the prerm script manually? For some reason the error is getting swallowed up.

Comment: You can actually edit that file. I suggest editing it, and adding a `set -x` at the top, which should show you where it failed out.

Answer (score 4):

In `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`,find file like `virtualbox-4.3.*`,and delete them all,then redo the remove action,it will be ok.

I just removed the openssh-server and solved the same problem.